# Code First Entity Framework Linq Statement Returning Missing Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ef-code-first

I have the following query:

```
orderMessageEmail.MessageChain = DbContext.Current
    .Messages
    .Where(c => 
        c.OrderId == orderMessageEmail.OrderId && 
        c.IsPublic && 
        c.MessageId != orderMessageEmail.MessageId && 
        c.MessageId < orderMessageEmail.MessageId
    )
    .Select(c => new OrderMessageChain()
    {
        CreateDateTime = c.CreateDateTime,
        MessageId = c.MessageId,
        Message = c.MessageData,
        UserFirstName = c.User.FirstName,
        UserLastName = c.User.LastName,
        CustomerFirstName = c.CustomerAccountPerson.FirstName,
        CustomerLastName = c.CustomerAccountPerson.LastName,
        SentFrom = c.SentFrom
    })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.MessageId)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

The problem I'm running into is that whenever `c.User` is null it doesn't return ANY record for the `OrderMessageChain`

I'd like to just have it return `UserFirstName` and `UserLastName` as empty strings instead of completely eliminating that `OrderMessageChain` from the list.

Does this make sense?

**One more thing..**

Simply testing this query:

```
var t = DbContext.Current
        .Messages
        .Include("User")
        .Where(c => 
         c.MessageId < 138120 && 
         c.OrderId == 170496 && 
         c.IsPublic)
         .ToList();
```

When I manually execute the same query in the DB i'm shown 3 records, however `t` is showing zero.

I always thought Include worked as a Left Join - is that not the case?

**One more thing...**

OK so i think i'm starting to realize what is going on here..

I didn't realize this, but it appears that the DBA setup the DB field UserId on the Message Table to NOT be nullable, however, in the case when there isn't a user record the `UserId` field contains a 0 (zero) value, instead of null... argh...

I think this is leading to code first to believe it should perform an inner join instead of a left join [per here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809817/entity-framework-include-command-left-or-inner-join)

So i'm not quite sure how to fix this.. is there anyway I can force code first to somehow perform a left join on that navigation property instead of an inner?

Comment: DbContext.Current.Include("User").....

Comment: `Include` should be used with an expression (`.Include( c => c.User )`) for best practice. Aside from that, the include statement will not affect the amount of records received from the database. The issue must be related to the where statement. I would suggest, purely for testing purposes and your own sanity :), to do the and clauses iteratively and just check their count to see which one strips everything out. Psuedo `var t1 = db.cur.m.where(c.mid < 138); int c1 = t1.Count(); var t2 = t1.where(c.oid == 170); int c2 = t2.Count(); var t3 = t2.where(c.ispublic); int c3 = t3.Count();`

Comment: If I remove the Include("User") the records appear - the only thing that sucks is that I want to have it in there so when there is a matching user record I can pull the name :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select the data you need, convert it to an IEnumerable and do the mapping in-memory, something like (the untested);

```cs
orderMessageEmail.MessageChain = DbContext.Current
    .Messages
    .Where(c => 
        c.OrderId == orderMessageEmail.OrderId && 
        c.IsPublic && 
        c.MessageId != orderMessageEmail.MessageId && 
        c.MessageId < orderMessageEmail.MessageId
    )
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.MessageId)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(c => new {
        c, u = c.User, cap = c.CustomerAccountPerson
    }). 
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new OrderMessageChain()
    {
        CreateDateTime = c.c.CreateDateTime,
        MessageId = c.c.MessageId,
        Message = c.c.MessageData,
        UserFirstName = c.u == null ? "" : c.u.FirstName,
        UserLastName = c.u == null ? "" : c.u.LastName,
        CustomerFirstName = c.cap == null ? "" : c.cap.FirstName,
        CustomerLastName = c.cap == null ? "" : c.cap.LastName,
        SentFrom = c.c.SentFrom
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting - I will try this, also, I updated my question with more findings of what I believe to be the reason for the problem, not sure if that changes anything

Comment: @99823 Ah, your last addition to the question may make this problematic too. You can always test, but I suspect it may fail in the same way.

Comment: One thing i'm hesitant about your solution, is that anytime I pull messages and want to include the User i'm going to have to do some crazy finagling instead of just using an Include statement - know what I mean? Not to say your solution won't work, I just wish I didn't have to go through all the extra stuff :p

Comment: @99823 If you need it to be automatic, you'll most likely need to update the mappings.

Comment: Yea - i just made the code first UserId property nullable, left the table the same and the query worked as I had wanted it to, i'm just afraid I will run into some issues down the road however with this setup if I don't properly fix the tables, but that introduces a whole new can of worms to deal w/ regarding our legacy apps using that DB... argh.. never easy ;)

Comment: @99823 'k, then you may want to delete the question or write up an answer yourself, this answer may not really apply with the fixed mappings :)

Comment: Joachim - thank you for your help, I really do appreciate it, I wish I could have awarded you the points. I'm going to delete this question, hope you see this before I delete the question - have a good day man :)