# Entity Framework force inner join with thenInclude

Tags: entity-framework

I have my EF framework query as below

```
.Include( d => d.Photos)
  .ThenInclude( p => p.File )
```

This produces a mysql query with outer join on file table. I get query as below

```
Select * from
photos as p
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT f.id
 FROM files AS f
) AS t40 ON p.file_id = t40.id
```

How can I ensure to have query as below? The reason to have a single line is because the above query does not use primary key index and the performance on the query is very high

```
Select * from
photos as p
INNER JOIN files as f on p.file_id = f.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will decide whether to use inner join or left join depending Include depending on the nullability of the included link.
You should have to check table Photos/File relationship.
Find more info in this answer ! [Entity framework Include command - Left or inner join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809817/entity-framework-include-command-left-or-inner-join)

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I can get inner join but is it possible to get single line join. I have updated my question

Comment: Could you post your full query ? 
Have you tried something like `(from p in _context.Photos
                            join f in _context.File
                            on p.file_id equals f.Id
                            select new {
                            PID = p.id,
                            FID = f.id, 
                            (keep on going)
                 }).ToList();`