# replace joins with navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

At the advice from people on here, I am trying to rewrite the linq query below using Navigation Properties.

I haven't gotten very far, because I'm not sure how to replace the joins in my Linq query with Navigation Properties.

So far I have this:

```
await _context.StarList(sl => new 
{
    sl.StarId,
    sl.StarType,
    sl.StarTitle,
    sl.ChemicalId...
}
```

But then, in the original query, I start using 'chemicalatoms' in the query.

So I'm not sure how to transition to them.

So my question is, how do I replace the joins in my original query with Navigation Properties?

Thanks!

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetStarChemicalData(string starID)
    {
        var starChemicalData = await (from starlist in _context.StarList
                                      join ql in _context.ChemicalList on starlist.ChemicalId equals ql.ChemicalId into stars
                                      from chemicallist in stars.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      join qc in _context.ChemicalAtoms on chemicallist.ChemicalId equals qc.ChemicalId into chemicals
                                      from chemicalatoms in chemicals.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      join nk in _context.StarLinks on chemicalatoms.AtomId equals nk.AtomId into links
                                      from starlinks in links.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      where starlist.StarId == starID
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          StarId = starlist.StarId,
                                          StarType = starlist.StarType,
                                          StarTitle = starlist.StarTitle,
                                          ChemicalId = starlist.ChemicalId,
                                          AtomId = (Guid?)chemicalatoms.AtomId,
                                          OrderId = chemicalatoms.OrderId,
                                          ChemicalText = chemicallist.ChemicalText,
                                          AtomText = chemicalatoms.AtomText,
                                          Wavelength = chemicalatoms.Wavelength,
                                          isRedShifted = (starlinks.AtomId != null && starlist.StarType == 1) ? 1
                                          : (starlinks.AtomId == null && starlist.StarType == 1) ? 0
                                          : (int?)null
                                      })
                                          .GroupBy(x => x.StarId)
                                          .Select(g => new
                                          {
                                              StarId = g.FirstOrDefault().StarId,
                                              StarType = g.FirstOrDefault().StarType,
                                              StarTitle = g.FirstOrDefault().StarTitle,
                                              ChemicalId = g.FirstOrDefault().ChemicalId,
                                              ChemicalText = g.FirstOrDefault().ChemicalText,
                                              ChemicalAtoms = (g.FirstOrDefault().AtomId != null ? g.Select(x => new
                                              {
                                                  AtomId = x.AtomId,
                                                  OrderId = x.OrderId,
                                                  AtomText = x.AtomText,
                                                  Feedback = x.Wavelength,
                                                  IsCorrect = x.isRedShifted
                                              }) : null)
                                          }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return starChemicalData;
```

Comment: Did you try using the `Include()` instead of `join`?

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan Hi, does that go in the Linq query?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284719/linq-include-vs-join-are-they-equivalent) post for more information.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan So instead of doing a "join" like this: `from starlist in _context.StarList join ql in _context.ChemicalList` , I'd replace that with `_context.StartList.Include("_context.ChemicalList")`?   Thanks!

Comment: Yeap, that's it, it will save your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above communication succeeded, I think I can sum up the results, here ))
So, instead of having this:

```cs
var starChemicalData = await (from starlist in _context.StarList
    join ql in _context.ChemicalList on starlist.ChemicalId equals ql.ChemicalId into stars
    from chemicallist in stars.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join qc in _context.ChemicalAtoms on chemicallist.ChemicalId equals qc.ChemicalId into chemicals
    from chemicalatoms in chemicals.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join nk in _context.StarLinks on chemicalatoms.AtomId equals nk.AtomId into links 
    ...
    );
```

we can have this:

```cs
_context.StarList.Include(st => st.ChemicalList)
    .Include(ca => ca.ChemicalAtoms)  // or ThenInclude, based on your relations
    .Include(sl => sl.StartLinks)
    ...
    Select(r => new {...})
    ...
```

---

Please note that what is essential when using [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) is that your relations(primary foreign key) should be set appropriately between your database tables you are using here.

Another important thing is that `Include()` will not bring a row result in case if one of your PK⟶FK relations contains `null` value, which it actually shouldn't.

Comment: Oh ok so if I want to use Include(), I need to make sure that each table has a primary key and that the primary key is also the foreign key in any table I want to include?  ThankS! For example, ChemicalList would have a primary key of ChemicalId.  Which would also be a foreign key in StarList?

Comment: Yeap, so that's how basically EF does the magic because otherwise, it will not know how the 2 tables are connected. In those scenarios, if the tables don't have relations properly set you can you the `join` (or when you want to make `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like in SQL), but otherwise save your time using the `Include` method.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. `Include` is an example of how to *use* navigation properties. You don't answer the question how to convert LINQ `join` statements into navigation properties.

Comment: Yes, I didn't convert the whole query, but I think I've shown an example of how to do that (check above) using the navigation properties with `Include`.